# In-line text replacement using sed, shell, or some other means

Tags: bash, shell, sed, find, haml

I want to pass two parameters to a program, a file name and a modified version of the file name. The situation is I have a bunch of .html.erb files in a directory tree, and I want invoke `html2haml` on them with the original filename and a new output filename with the haml extension, like so:

```
html2haml thing.html.erb thing.html.haml
```

Here's my current best attempt at this:

```
find . -name "*.html.erb" -exec echo {} `echo {} | sed "s/.erb/.haml/g"` \;
```

(after I'm done testing I'll replace `echo` with `html2haml` and run it again)

However it doesn't work. The result of the expression inside backticks is the unmodified string.

Here are some experiments I tried which **DO behave as expected** (to test if my syntax and levels of escaping/quotes were correct):

```
1. echo myfile.foo | sed 's/foo/foo2/g'
2. find . -name "*.html.erb" -exec echo {} `echo xyz | sed "s/y/Y/g"` \;
3. find . -name "*.html.erb" -exec echo {} `echo {} hello` \;
4. find . -name "*.html.erb" -exec echo {} `echo {}` \;
```

**The fact that these all behave as expected suggest to me that I am getting some small thing wrong in the syntax, and that is is indeed possible to do this with a one-liner.**

If this is impossible, it might be because of a misunderstanding about "when" find inserts its results on each invocation. example #3 above suggest to me that it does it exactly when i need/expect it to (because I'm successfully concatenating each individual result string with "hello").

Comment: the answer to this question has made its way into this pull request: https://github.com/haml/html2haml/pull/29 :-D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have `gsed`:

```
find . -name \*.erb -print0 | gsed -z 'p;s/.erb$/.haml/' | xargs -0 -n2 html2haml
```

If you don't have `gsed` and only have `sed`, this will work, **but only if none of your file names have whitespace**.

```
find . -name \*.erb -print | sed 'p;s/.erb$/.haml/' | xargs -n2 html2haml
```

---

Discussion about these and other techniques follows:

I have different versions of sed - my `GNU sed` is called `gsed`, if your `sed` is GNU - instead of `gsed` use `sed`.

You can check your `sed` with the `sed --version`, if prints something like:

> ```
> sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2
> Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> ```

You have a GNU sed.

The above - for the next `find`

```
$ find . -name \*foo -print 
./a/test.foo
./b/c/test.foo
./b/te st.foo         #<- note the filename with space
./b/test.foo
```

the above command produces:

```
$find . -name \*foo -print0 | gsed -z 'p;s/foo$/foo2/' | xargs -0 -n2 echo bar
bar ./a/test.foo ./a/test.foo2
bar ./b/c/test.foo ./b/c/test.foo2
bar ./b/te st.foo ./b/te st.foo2
bar ./b/test.foo ./b/test.foo2
```

Without additional scripts or functions. ;)

or you can replace the `sed` with `perl`, so the next

```
find . -name \*foo -print0 | perl  -n0le 'print;s/foo/foo2/;print' | xargs -0 -n2 echo bar
```

produces the same result:

```
bar ./a/test.foo ./a/test.foo2
bar ./b/c/test.foo ./b/c/test.foo2
bar ./b/te st.foo ./b/te st.foo2
bar ./b/test.foo ./b/test.foo2
```

IF you REALLY want to do it within one find, try:

```
find . -name \*html.erb -exec sh -c 'echo html2haml "{}" "$(echo "{}" | sed 's/\.erb/\.haml/')"' \;
```

or elimitating two useless echo the final command:

```
find . -name \*html.erb -exec sh -c 'html2haml "{}" "$(sed 's/\.erb/\.haml/'<<<"{}")"' \;
```

Comment: lovely. but as you suspected, doesn't work with my sed. (bsd on os x) :-) and i'm looking for as generic a solution as possible so it can be put in the documentation for some software. any ideas for doing find/replace with a more common tool, and keeping it a one-liner? (or, more generic sed syntax?)

Comment: i've clarified and expanded my question -- check it out.

Comment: it works! does that sed syntax work with your gsed? here's my final invocation: `find . -name \*.erb -print | sed 'p;s/.erb$/.haml/' | xargs -n2 html2haml`

Comment: @JohnBachir added `one find` example too

Comment: @JohnBachir the `-print` version (so, no -print0) verison works, but filenames *must not* contain spaces.

Comment: okay, nice, so you've gotten closer to fixing my original attempt. i see you jumped up a level of abstraction and generated a shell script to execute -- is this necessary or was it just the easiest way for you to think about it? put another way: what exactly is wrong with original attempt (second code block in my question)?

Comment: @JohnBachir you need exceute the shell, because youre doing pipes and command sobtitutions and soo - all are shell features. Without shell it does nothing

Comment: but if it's inside the backticks isn't that the same as being inside a shell?

Comment: @JohnBachir iMHO, the backtick are interpreted by shell, chicken&eggs problem ;) you need shell to interpret backtick. And one last thing: The sh -c must be `sh = bash` for the nested """" and so.. or use `bash -c`

Comment: thanks for all the versions and discussion! great stuff. I find the xargs version to be the most clear and readable and reusable so i'm sticking with that. i modified your answer so the solutions are at the top -- feel free to revert my changes if you don't like it.

Answer (score 1):

What about a loop?

```
find . -name "*.html.erb" | while read file
do
    haml_file=${file%.erb}.haml
    html2haml $file $haml_file
done
```

The `${var%glob}` syntax takes an environment variable `${var}` and filters out the smallest portion of the right side that matches `glob`.

Comment: I'd like it to be a one-liner. I clarified and expanded my question, check it out.

Comment: With any Bourne compatible shell, you an enter this script right from a command line. I do it all the time in Kornshell and BASH.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the filename ends with `.foo`, then you can use:

```
do_something "$filename" "${filename%.foo}.foo2"
```

(In the unlikely case that you really want to just put a `2` on the end, you could of course just use `"${filename}2"`. But I assume the `foo` and `foo2` are to be substituted with less similar strings.)

If you want to invoke `do_something` from `find`, your best bet would be to pass it only one filename (or, better, a number of filenames each of them representing a single operation). For example:

```
-- do_something.sh

#!/bin/bash

# This is the definition of what you want to do.
# It is called as `bar old_filename new_filename`
bar() {
  # For example
  mv "$1" "$2"
}

for filename in "$@"; do
  bar "$filename" "${filename%.foo}.foo2"
done


-- find command:
find . -type f -name '*.foo' -exec do_something.sh {} +
```

If you really need to use `sed` (for something that you can't even do with the `bash` replace syntax, `${var/pattern/substitution}`), then set up `do_something` as above, but replace the line inside the `for` loop with, for example:

```
  bar "$filename" "$(sed -r 's/([^.]+)\.([^.]+)$/\2.\1/' <<<"$filename")"
```

Explanation: The above `sed` expression (gnu-specific) flips the last two extensions around, so it would change `some.file.html.en` into `some.file.en.html`. `-r` causes gnu sed to use extended regex format, which I find more readable. `<<<` is a bashism which expands the word following it and feeds it into `stdin`, somewhat similar to `echo "$filename" | sed ...` but without creating another subprocess.

Comment: what i want to do is change the file extension on certain files within a tree. i've modified my question so that it's describing my actual use case, hopefully it's more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can call your find like this:

```
find . -name "*.html.erb" -print0 -print0|xargs -0 -J % html2haml % | sed 's/\.erb$/.haml/'
```

This will result in executing:

```
html2haml thing.html.erb thing.html.haml
```

Comment: i'd like it to be a one-liner -- i've clarified and expanded my question, take a look.